# Tiles, copy visual as image in powerbi using rest api

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-custom-visuals, powerbi-rest-api

I am new in Powerbi. I have requirement to download tiles using powerbi api. tiles reside at below url.

```
https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/apps/{appid}/reports/{reportid}/{ReportSection}
```

I have access to app, i can see the reports in Powerbi.

I have seen powerbi api documentation. when i try with [powerbi api UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/apps/get-report#code-try-0) i get error as Response Code: 404

> {"error":{"code":"PowerBIEntityNotFound","pbi.error":{"code":"PowerBIEntityNotFound","parameters":{},"details":[],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using incorrect URL, Tiles are part of Dashboards but the URL that you mentioned is for Report.

Your URL for the tile component will be something like:

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/apps/{appId}/dashboards/{dashboardId}/tiles/{tileId}
```

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/apps/get-tile